# How do I change the color of the markers and width of the figure in this boxplot using seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

Using seaborn I want to change the color of the outlier markers to red. I also want to reduce the width of the figure to get rid of the whitespcace.

This is my current code and the graph it produces:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rbp_box = sns.boxplot(data=df_raw, y="Resting blood pressure", color="red", flierprops={"marker": "x"}, width=0.2)
rbp_box.set(xlabel='', ylabel='mm Hg', title='Resting blood pressure box plot')
```

[box plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6diV.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! To change the color of outliers, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68731037/7789963).

Comment: And to change the figure size, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31594549/7789963).